# Prove $A\rightarrow 0$ iff $A^2\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis

The implication from left to right is pretty easy. But the implication from right to left does not work. I tried to proof by contradiction by supposing $A^2$ converges to some number not 0 for the sake of contradiction. But it turns out we do not even know if it converges or not! Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: *Hint* If $A\not\to 0$, then $A^2\not\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused about what you're trying to prove; assuming that $A^2$ converges to anything but zero is not going to help you prove the implication from the right to the left. What you *should* do to show the implication right to left, if you want to do a proof by contradiction, would be to assume that $A$ does not converge to zero and prove that $A^2$ may not converge to zero either. I would expect this to be of similar difficulty to what you've already done.

Comment: But you do not even know if A converges or not. So it is not helpful

Comment: You don't really *need* to do this, but you can split into cases from "A does not converge to zero" - you could have "A converges to something other than zero" and "A does not converge" as subcases, and handle them separately. But "A does not converge to zero" is enough, since you can from that say that infinitely many values of $A$ are not in some interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and hence $A^2$ has infinitely many values not in $[0,\varepsilon^2)$, contradicting that it might converge to $0$.